# Siddhi Pattern with occurrences on Aggregation

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

I have the query like -
"from every e1 = inputStream[ name == 'A']<3> within 1 min select unionSet(createSet(e1.id)) as id_set, 'rule1' as ruleId insert into outputStream"

I am getting only getting [id1] in id_set, I expect [id1,id2,id3] in id_set, if the pattern support aggregation over within time period.

When I try this with windows.
"from inputStream[name == 'A']#window.time(20 sec) select 'rule2' as ruleId,unionSet(createSet(id)) as id_set insert into outputStream"

I am getting [id1,id2,id3] in id_set.

Is there a way so that I can get aggregation from the pattern within a time period as we specified in within clause?

Answer (score 0):

Siddhi does not support getting e1 as a list as of now.

A workaround is suggested in https://github.com/siddhi-io/siddhi/issues/1398